# Как проверить мой ip с cidr?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет! Использую MaxMind

Импортнул в базу таблицу городов и ip

в поле network хранятся вот такие записи 2.3.116.0/24

я получаю например ip 37.212.32.249 как мне вывести по этому ip 37.212.32.249 из базы?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11121861/407561 (В поддерживаемых форматах есть CIDR)

Comment: да, но в laravel я не могу создать поле типа cidr там есть только ipAddress

Comment: пример https://pgregg.com/projects/php/ip_in_range/test.php